# return a value with ajax through callback

Tags: php, ajax, callback, return

So i've found plenty of answers to this question, but I can't seem to wrap my head around it.

I want to return a value with ajax through a callback.

below is the php accessed by ajax

```
<?php
session_start();

$filename = '../tempUploads/i'.$_SESSION['user'].'.'.$_SESSION['imageExt'];

if ( file_exists($filename) ) {
    echo 1;
}
else {
    echo 0;
}

?>
```

below is the javascript

```
alert( imageExist(mycallback) ); //I want this to echo either 1 or 0

function mycallback(data) {
    return data;
}

function imageExist(callback) {

    $.ajax({
        url:'../php/imageExist.php',
        success:callback
    });

}
```

I'm sure there are more than a few ways to do this. I understand that ajax is asynchronous, and can't return values. I don't want to make it synchronous. I also don't want to use the promise/defer thing (.done etc). I want to understand how to do it this way, then i'll try the other ways.

Thanks all.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return the response from an AJAX call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call)

Comment: *"I understand that ajax is asynchronous, and can't return values."* Then why are you asking? *"I don't want to make it synchronous."* Good!  *"I also don't want to use the promise/defer thing (.done etc)."* Ooh :( *"I want to understand how to do it this way"* You can't. *"then i'll try the other ways"* Do it!

Answer (score 0):

You made a slight mistake.

If you want to alert the data you have to do this in your callback function:

```
imageExist(mycallback); //I want this to echo either 1 or 0

function mycallback(data) {
    alert(data);
    //return data;
}

function imageExist(callback) {

    $.ajax({
        url:'../php/imageExist.php',
        success:callback
    });
}
```

This is because imageExist will start the ajax call and then return nothing.

Comment: i would i return the 'data', so imageExist(mycallback)==data

Comment: This would only work if you would do an synchronous ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

The return you are doing inside the callback doesn't work because you are passing the callback to the ajax method which will then run it. It is not the alert call that is running the callback and therefore would not get the return.

Answer (score 0):

That is right. Asynchronous ajax always split the code into two pieces:

1. request
2. and after some delay ... response